# Flask-Bootstrap not response for the change

Tags: python, flask

I'm a new developer and I'm working now with a flask-bootstrap but when I edit some of the tags or style and run the command:

`python example.py  runserver`

nothing changes even if I clear the browser cache. I wonder if there is another command I can run it to apply the changes.

Comment: You need to set `debug=True`

Comment: It did not works .  are python example.py  runserver is correct to use it with flask-bootstrap?

Comment: Runserver is from django....app.run is usually used in flask

Comment: can you  show your code here?